# Aggrid create column which displays value for certain group

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an aggrid table which uses row grouping

```
 {
  field: 'day',
  hide: true,
  rowGroup: true,
  cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
},
{
  field: 'shift',
  hide: true,
  rowGroup: true,
  cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
}

...

groupDisplayType: 'groupRows',
groupRowRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is to add a column `Value if Grouped` which displays values only on the grouped row `shift` (`Break`, `Early Shift`, `Late Shift`). Not in the `day` row, nor in a `leaf`.

I tried several things but without success.

I thought I just create a simple column with cellRenderer

```
{
  colId: 'Value if Grouped',
  cellRenderer: (params) => {
    if (params.node.group === 'shift') { // is just pseudecode
      return '123';
    }
  }
}
```

But the cell renderer is only called when I open the group and am on leaf-level.

Any ideas how I can write code to just display a value on the group level `day`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the aggregate function and cell renderer. [Plunker Demo Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8I8sPBk8XZLMhuHL?preview)

```
{
  field: 'total',
  aggFunc: 'sum',
  cellRenderer: (params) => {
      return params.node.level === 0 ? params.node.aggData.total : '' 
  }
},
```

[image]

Comment: note: I noticed this does work with default settings. However in my initial example I use the `groupDisplayType: groupRows`. Here it does not work. But as I am currently thinking, I think it does not make sense in `groupRows` anyhow